# How to reboot Windows 10 [UEFI] after Linux (Fedora 24) Legacy installation?

Tags: fedora, windows, dual-boot, uefi

Recently I tried installing Linux in my laptop to dual boot with Windows 10, but I accidently did it in Legacy mode. I created a separate partition with 20gb for Linux and installed it in that partition. Through Linux I know that none of my other drives are affected as all the files are intact.

I'm able to use Linux through Legacy boot with no problems. I'm unable to boot Windows through UEFI boot configuration as it throws a "disk not found" error.

Q: Can someone please help me reboot to Windows 10???

Laptop Details: Acer Aspire 8gb RAM 2.6 GHz 700gb Drive

PS: If solution requires Fedora to be uninstalled, that would not be a problem.

Comment: I'm wondering if you re-installed Fedora with UEFI, maybe everything would just work then. I.e., Windows 10 boot would appear in the grub menu, etc.

Comment: I have not reinstalled Fedora in UEFI mode. I did think of this but I don't know how it will affect my existing legacy installation. Do I need to uninstall the legacy mode beforehand? Also I need to pass some barriers in UEFI mode which I don't know how to do without Windows

Comment: In the last year, I've dual-booted 2 Windows 10 laptops, both UEFI. I didn't modify any of the BIOS. Fedora works fine with UEFI. If I were you, I would revert BIOS to however it was for your Windows 10 OS and then just install Fedora 25  in the space you allocated already.

Comment: When I try to install Fedora in UEFI mode, it says "the current system privacy policy prevents booting from flash drive". I'm unable to disable secure boot as well in UEFI as well (it appears in a grey colour). Apparently I need Windows to disable the secure boot, although that is my initial problem.

Comment: Are you sure there is no BIOS control for "Boot from USB"?

Comment: there is an option for boot from usb, the security policy does not allow me to go further. I understand I have to disable secure boot, but I don't know how to do that without Windows.

Comment: I don't know your BIOS, but I would be very surprised if you couldn't control everything you need to boot from there. See if [this](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) helps.

Comment: I figured out how to disable secure boot, but it was too late as I deleted all partitions and reinstalled windows from scratch. Thanks for the help, I'll install Fedora in uefi next time using the right options.